# Sepia filter inverting

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I stacked with inverting sepia filter.
The result of inverting the filter is not as expected.

My logic is the following:
processed_pixel = np.dot(sepia_filter, original_pixel)

It means that:
original_pixel = np.dot(np.inverse(sepia_filter), processed_pixel)

Here's code I've tried - I've also tried a couple of other approaches, such as reversing colours individually and then solving a system of linear equations but get the same result, so I assume that I don't understand something crucial.

Requirements:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
```

Sepia filter code:

```
def get_pixel_after_sepia(source, pixel, sepia_filter):
    colors = np.array(source.getpixel(pixel)) 
    colors_new = tuple(map(int, np.dot(sepia_filter,colors))) + (255,) #  apply filter, transform results to ints, cut to 255
    return colors_new
                       
def sepia(source, result_name):
    result = Image.new('RGB', source.size)
    sepia_filter = np.array([[0.393,0.769,0.189], [0.349,0.686,0.168], [0.272,0.534,0.131]])

    #  for every pixel                   
    for x in range(source.size[0]):
        for y in range(source.size[1]):
            new_pixel = get_pixel_after_sepia(source, (x,y), sepia_filter)
            result.putpixel((x, y),new_pixel)
            
    result.save(result_name, "JPEG")
    return result
```

Inverted sepia code:

```
def get_pixel_before_sepia(source, pixel, inversed_sepia_filter):
    colors = np.array(source.getpixel(pixel)) 
    colors_new = tuple(map(int, np.dot(inversed_sepia_filter, colors)))+ (255,)
    return colors_new

def inverse_sepia(image_with_sepia, result_file):
    result = Image.new('RGB', image_with_sepia.size) 
    sepia_filter = np.array([[0.393,0.769,0.189], [0.349,0.686,0.168], [0.272,0.534,0.131]])
    inverse_sepia_filter = np.linalg.inv(sepia_filter)
    
    for x in range(image_with_sepia.size[0]):
        for y in range(image_with_sepia.size[1]):
            new_pixel = get_pixel_before_sepia(image_with_sepia, (x,y), inverse_sepia_filter)
            result.putpixel((x, y),new_pixel)
            
    result.save(result_file, "JPEG")
    return result
```

Functions execution:

```
image = Image.open("original_image.jpg")
filtered_image = sepia(image, "filtered.jpg") # result_pixel = dot_product(Filter, origin_pixel)  
image_after_filter_reversing = inverse_sepia(filtered_image,'restored.jpg' ) # result_pixel = dot_product(Filter^(-1), filtering_result_pixel)
```

Original image

[image]

Filtered_image

[image]

Image_after_filter_reversing

[image]

---

I understand that it's impossible to make perfect reverse since we are cutting results of calculation and rounding them to int. But I expect the image after reversing to be quite close to the original.
I'm a novice in image processing, but mathematically problem looks perfectly valid for me.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that mysepia inverting Algorithm Isn't working properly

Comment: Can you be more specific? Because we cannot run your code. Do you get error messages or is the result not what you expect it to be?

Comment: Sorry - the results aren't as expected.

Comment: I've added images to illustrate the problem.

Comment: what happens if you feed the `filtered_image` into the `inverse_sepia` function?

Comment: That's actually what I'm doing. Just has a typo in code initially posted - sorry.

Comment: I had some new insight. See my comments under David's answer.

Comment: @mapf Thanks for your insights. I'm just trying to figure out how filters works, so you are right - I always have an original. Your thoughts were very helpful. I'll also try your idea with storing values without clipping and show results here if you are interested once I'll have some free time.

Comment: No worries! But if I understand user3386109's answer correctly, my idea wont work either.

Comment: @mapf Yes, as I understand from explanation - it's true. But I'm just curious what the result will be.

Comment: If you are interested in restoring images, take a look at how GANs have been used for a similar type of task: [DeOldify](https://github.com/jantic/DeOldify), [Colorizing-with-GANs](https://github.com/ImagingLab/Colorizing-with-GANs)

Comment: @dhanushka Thanks for links. I'm just trying to find out how filtering works in details - there's no real project behind my question, just studying. But I'll know how to approach such problems in future :) BTW restoring looks impressive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An interesting question.
The answer may be a little disappointing: a sepia filter is **not** reversible in theory, or in practice.

### Theory

The **numeric** matrix used in the code is:

```
0.393   0.769   0.189
0.349   0.686   0.168
0.272   0.534   0.131
```

The corresponding **symbolic** matrix is:

```
 x       y       z
mx      my      mz
nx      ny      nz
```

where `x=0.393 y=0.769 z=0.189 m=0.89 n=0.69`.
When you compute the determinant of the symbolic matrix, it is zero.  Hence, the matrix is not invertible, and neither is the sepia filter.

The fact that the numeric matrix has a non-zero determinant is simply due to the limited precision (3 digits) of the numbers. Computing the determinant of the numeric matrix gives 0.000000121, which is essentially 0, plus/minus a few rounding errors.

As a side note, multiplying a pixel value by the numeric matrix is equivalent to the following calculations

```
R = 0.393*r + 0.769*g + 0.189*b
G = 0.89*R
B = 0.69*R
```

where 'rgb' is the original pixel value, and 'RGB' is the sepia pixel value.

### Practice

The New Oxford American Dictionary defines sepia as *"a reddish-brown color associated particularly with monochrome photographs of the 19th and early 20th centuries"*

The key word is **monochrome**. What sepia encodes is the **apparent brightness** of every pixel in the image. It retains none of the **color** information in the original image. This may seem counterintuitive since the sepia image appears to have some color in it.

To get a better understanding, try the following matrix in your code

```
0.291  0.569  0.140
0.291  0.569  0.140
0.291  0.569  0.140
```

That will convert the image into a grayscale image, aka a black and white image. Like sepia, the grayscale image encodes only the apparent brightness of each pixel. It retains none of the color information. The difference is that grayscale is using a gray hue as the base color, whereas sepia uses a brown hue as the base color. The other colors you see in a sepia image: orange, peach, yellow, and black are just different brightness levels of brown in the RGB colorspace.

Another difference between grayscale and sepia is that sepia is able to encode more levels of brightness. Grayscale has a palette of 256 shades. Sepia has 346 different pixel values. The reason is clipping. Given an input pixel of `(255, 255, 255)` the corresponding sepia pixel is `(345, 307, 239)` before clipping, and `(255, 255, 239)` after clipping. The red component of a sepia pixel has 346 possible values before clipping. For each red value, the green and blue values are proportional (`G=0.89*R` and `B=0.69*R`).

Here's the sepia palette (minus the four darkest shades):

[image]

Hence, the practical problem you face is that the original color image has a palette of 16 million colors, whereas the sepia image has a palette of only 346 colors. There's no way to recreate the original image, since a pixel in the sepia image corresponds to any of roughly 48000 possible colors in the original.

Answer (score 3):

Now that you fixed the code, the lamb is sort of recognizable, but there's a lot of clipping going on. I think the problem is that the sepia filter, while invertible, is almost singular. You can see in the [SVD](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=SVD%5B%7B%7B0.393%2C0.769%2C0.189%7D%2C+%7B0.349%2C0.686%2C0.168%7D%2C+%7B0.272%2C0.534%2C0.131%7D%7D%5D) how one of the singular values is much larger than the others. Thus small changes, as with the truncation to obtain an integer value (you might try rounding instead, might be a little better) get magnified a lot by the inverse operation, which results in the inaccurate looking reconstruction.

Comment: That sounds like a good explanation. I've tried the code with simpler data and it worked. So the real question is, how do you make it work?

Comment: @mapf The problem is that the sepia filter plus rounding is lossy, so you can't, really. The best you can do is probably something like adding careful dithering to the sepia filter and then adding a blur after the inverse filter, but we're getting far out of my wheelhouse.

Comment: Hm interesting. This gives me an idea.

Comment: Ok, so I'm too tired to try this out myself, but basically what you do is, after you have applied your sepia filter to a pixel, you compare the pixel to the old one to get the 'actual' matrix that was applied to it, as in, the one that would produce the new pixel without clipping. then you store that information somewhere. By the end, the inverse of all those 'actual' transformations should give you the real inverse of the sepia filter.

Comment: In any case, I also understand now why this is of couse not trivial. Because either you don't know the sepia filter and have to rework it manually, aka image restoration which is like a super specialized job (or use AI), or you've applied the filter yourself. In that case, you also have the original so you don't need an inverse filter.

Comment: * By proportional equations I mean that system of equations is linearly dependent.

Comment: @StasBuzuluk they're not linearly dependent -- just very close. That's why I talk about singular values.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Yes, your answer is totally correct -  I just don't know math good enough to understand it properly. Now - I see that you actually tried to show me the same problem.
Thanks for your answer and further explanations - if you don't mind - I'll leave another answer marked as correct, despite the fact that you were first, just since it's a bit simpler for people with little or now knowledge in linear algebra as myself.